Run initialisation directly after all beans have initialised Spring Boot
Outline
I have a event registry class that simply scans all component classes' methods and registers them if the methods have a certain annotation present. This functionality works perfectly fine, however the scanning should occur only after all Beans have been initialised. It is hard to find this explicit functionality in spring boot. I went with a spring boot runner (either ApplicationRunner or CommandLineRunner), but they do not work when registered in my config file.
Config Class
I only use annotation configs as I like the pure java approach. I have a SpringApplicationRunListener that automatically adds my config file to the context and is registered in META-INF:
package groupid.discord;

// imports ...

public class DiscordRunListener implements SpringApplicationRunListener {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    public void contextLoaded(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

        annotationContext.setParent(context);
        annotationContext.register(BotConfiguration.class);
        annotationContext.refresh();

        annotationContext.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}

My config file contains the runner:
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> {
            // initialisation ...
        };
    }

With some debugging I figured out that the runner was being instantiated, but never run by spring.
Debugging & Suspicions
I tried the same command line runner in a test config which I set up to be detected by component scanning in under the main package (groupid.artifactid) and it was instantiated and run as expected. My main suspicion is that it has something to do with the registration of the configuration class in the run listener. I furthermore tried event listeners and realised that only the ContextRefreshedEvent was working and therefore I am pretty sure about the context initialisation suspicion.
Main Question: why does the run listener not work and what is the fix?
Subsidiary Question: Is there a better way of doing it, while keeping in the style of automatic configuration and instantiation as with spring boot?

What you are asking for are the Spring Application Events. Well explained here: https://medium.com/@truongbui95/spring-boots-application-events-36ebe09e9313

Please note my mention that the only functioning event is the ContextRefreshEvent. I suspect that the events are called only from the specific application context which registered the beans, in this case, the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext which I instantiated to register the config class and subsequently refresh.
